# Fetch recursion using javascript to call Google place API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to get a list of results from a Google place API request. The API allows 20 results per page ans I need all results available so I need to go to the next page.The next page is accessible from a token given in the response of the previous request. 
I've implemented the code below:

```
function request(url){
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}
```

This is my recursive function:

```
export function getListOfActivitiesInACity(city_name,nextPageToken,datas){
  const first_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=activity+in+'+city_name+'&key='+ API_TOKEN +'&language=fr'
  const next_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken='+nextPageToken+'&key='+ API_TOKEN
  var url = nextPageToken ===''? first_url : next_url;
  return request(url)
      .then((data) => {
      const newData = [...datas, data];
      if(data["next_page_token"] !== undefined){
        return getListOfActivitiesInACity(city_name,data["next_page_token"],newData);
      }
      return newData;
    })
}
```

And then I call my function and print results

```
var datas=[];
    getListOfActivitiesInACity("Lyon",'',datas)
    .then(data => {console.log(data);})
```

The first iteration of the fetch works fine and gives me the good new url for the next fetch
(I tried it on my broser directy and it works)
But the second fetch return me this :

```
Object {
  "html_attributions": Array [],
  "results": Array [],
  "status": "INVALID_REQUEST",
}
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work , so please can anyone help Thanks

Comment: You can't do that. The API expects this to happen on user action, not by sending all requests within a loop in your code so there is a small delay between when the token is issued and when it can be used. This is somewhere in the docs...

Comment: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses) says: *`next_page_token` contains a token that can be used to return up to 20 additional results. A `next_page_token` will not be returned if there are no additional results to display. The maximum number of results that can be returned is 60. There is a short delay between when a `next_page_token` is issued, and when it will become valid.*

Comment: Ok I understand, I will try to find another way to use less data .Tnahk you for your response